# El Capitan "Create NAT64 Network" - connection issues

Tags: network, macos, ipv6

I am trying to test apps for IPv6 according to Apple's documentation at [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html). I have difficulties connecting from the iPad to my *app* server.

**My Network Layout:**

[image: My Network Layout]

The Fritzbox has IPv6 support turned on with 6to4 enabled, because my provider does not have IPv6. I ran a set of tests with IPv6 turned off. The result was the same (see list of test items below).

*macmedia* runs El Capitan and runs iTunes serving as a media server.

*macsrv* runs El Capitan and OS X Server 5 with DNS, DHCP, File Sharing, Web, Wiki.

**My Test Process:**

I can set up the NAT64 network as described in the Apple document (in "Settings" hold option key, press "Sharing", then "Internet Sharing" and release option key).

I ran some tests, one of them looked like this:

- turn on NAT64 on *macsrv*
- in iPad Air WLAN settings select NAT64 network
- the blue checkmark appears in front of the network name
- the blue i-icon delivers this:

  - IP 169.254.55.58 / mask 255.255.0.0
  - DNS 2001:2:0:aab1::1
  - all other fields empty
- in Safari on iPad Air:

  - `https://www.google.com/` -> takes a long time, eventually a message like: "Could not open the page, because the server does not respond any more."
  - `http://macsrv:8989/` -> could not find server
  - `http://macsrv.local:8989/` -> "It works!" (Just looked at the logs: The access in apache2 was logged with the IPv6 address of the en0 interface of *macsrv*)
  - `http://192.168.1.11:8989/` -> Error like "Could not open page, because the iPad is not connected to the internet." (192.168.1.11 is *macsrv*)
  - `http://[2001:2::aab1:129a:ddff:fe4f:38f8]:80` -> takes a long time, eventually a message like: "Could not open the page, because the server does not respond any more." (like google.com; the address is the IPv6 address of the en0 interface on *macsrv*)
  - `http://192.168.1.115:8088/` -> Error like "Could not open page, because the iPad is not connected to the internet."
  - `http://app.intra.admadic.com:8088/` -> could not find server (this is the same as 192.168.1.115)

Once I connected the iPad Air to the *macrsv* NAT64 network and it received the IP address 192.168.2.2. This happened never again.

When I start the NAT64 network on *macmedia*, the iPad cannot connect and the activity indicator keeps spinning forever.

**NAT64 Details:**

I looked for processes running when NAT64 is enabled:

```
/usr/libexec/InternetSharing
rtadvd -c /etc/com.apple.mis.rtadvd.conf -f -s bridge100
unbound -c /etc/com.apple.mis.unbound.conf -d
```

There are two config files related to `com.apple.mis...`:

/etc/com.apple.mis.rtadvd.conf:

```
bridge100:\
     nolladdr:maxinterval#135:mininterval#45:rltime#1800:addr="2001:2:0:aab1::":prefixlen#64:rdnssaddrs#1:rdnssaddr="2001:2:0:aab1::1"
```

/etc/com.apple.mis.unbound.conf:

```
server:
    chroot: ""
    pidfile: "/etc/unbound.pid"
    chroot: ""
    directory: "/etc"
    username: ""
    do-daemonize: no
    access-control: ::0/0 allow
    module-config: "dns64 iterator"
    dns64-synthall: yes
    dns64-prefix: 64:ff9b::/96
    interface: ::0
forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 192.168.1.11
```

I checked these conf files on *macsrv* and *macmedia* and they are identical in every detail.

**Questions:**

Q1. What could be the reason for NAT64 not working on *macmedia*?

Q2. Can I convince the NAT64 network to use my intranet DNS?

Q3. What could be the reason for NAT64 on *macsrv* to be sometimes working and sometimes not?

Q4. Why does the iPad get an 169.254.55.58 IPv4 address? (Shouldn't it only have IPv6 when connecting to NAT64?)

Q5: Do the com.apple.mis... conf files look ok? (having 192.168.1.11 as forward looks fine to me...)

Comment: I assume that you are trying to test the scenario shown in Figure 10-2 of the linked Apple documentation. Then please add the IPv6/v4 config of all devices.

Comment: @klanomath I added some information, will add later more of the iPad. (Have to do some other things for the next hour)

Comment: I've already setup a similar environment using a thumb drive (with 10.11.1), the remains of my network and an older iPhone but my iPhone can't even connect to the local (iMac) Wi-Fi. BTW how (or where) did you create the network scheme?

Comment: You mean the diagram? The software is called yEd - their homepage is at http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/ . It's free, it works on all platforms (Java); sometimes it has its rough edges, but it works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your network configuration correctly, your setup is completely hosed.

You need two separate (physical) networks:

- one with IPv4 only (e.g. ethernet)
- one with IPv6 only (e.g. local Wi-Fi)

Depending of the capabilities of your machines, the machine with two interfaces (ethernet and Wi-Fi) should be the server (DNS/DHCP etc.)/NAT64-router (= *macsrv*).

Since the iDevices don't have an ethernet interface and you try to test their IPv6/IPv4 functionality they should reside in the Wi-Fi section, which should be dedicated to IPv6 then. This local Wi-Fi network is **not** your Fritz!Box' Wi-Fi! You have to setup a personal hotspot on the NAT64 router!

To access a IPv4 server from your iDevices you may either use your normal router connection to the WAN or a dedicated IPv4 "server" (= *macmedia*) - both of them reside in the ethernet section "behind" the NAT64-router (= *macsrv*).
If *macmedia* doesn't have an ethernet interface just connect it to the Fritz!Box Wi-Fi, because technically the Fritz!Box Wi-Fi and the Fritz!Box ethernet are both in the ethernet section.

To access an IPv6 server use a web server on *macsrv*.

Since you don't need IPv6 on your Fritz!Box router, simply turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I turned on IPv6 on the FritzBox for testing whether iDevices can connect without NAT64 and they could. I will turn it off and run a test. The Fritzbox has WiFi turned off all the time. The NAT64 is created on macsrv by opening a WiFi network just for the NAT64 network. (macmedia and macsrv have a usually unused WiFi, which I use to test NAT64). So the NAT64 dedicated WiFi is there (via macsrv). Still it does not seem to work?

Comment: I forgot to mention: All machines and the Fritzbox are connected by wire. There are WiFis created by Apple Airport Extreme boxes which I usually use for the iDevices, but these should not interfere with the NAT64 WiFi on macsrv.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze What's the purpose of *app* (the Windows machine)?

Comment: The *app* machine hosts the test server (Rails) in a VM to which the iPad app shall connect.

Comment: You mentioned that to access an IPv6 server I should use a web server on *macsrv*. Shouldn't be the point of NAT64 be that I access an IPv4 server? So far I cannot access any server, neither on *macsrv* nor anywhere else.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze Just for testing purposes. One ipv6 server running on *macsrv* and one ipv4 server running on *macmedia*/some wan server in the internet.

Comment: I added more details about another test which I ran.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out if your `/usr/libexec/unbound` works properly with DNS queries coming via UDPv6. I encountered [a similar issue](https://gist.github.com/azolotko/49bdeaa2854f25a0f3cb2c079732713c) and was able to solve it by recompiling unbound from [source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-543/unbound/). I've reported the issue to Apple, so hopefully, it will get solved someday.